# How can I change the label color of the graph

Tags: flutter, charts, dart, flutter-layout

I wanna change the label color of the graph.

I'm using google's charts library (https://github.com/google/charts).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the color using `axis`

```
var axis = charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
            labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 10, color: charts.MaterialPalette.white), //chnage white color as per your requirement.
            ));
```

And define in the graph

```
primaryMeasureAxis: axis,
      domainAxis: axis,
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!
it worked only for primaryMeasureAxis but didn't work for domainAxis 
the error is below

flutter: The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector(state:
flutter: RawGestureDetectorState#3ed6c(gestures: [tap])):
flutter: type 'NumericAxisSpec' is not a subtype of type 'AxisSpec<String>'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’ve accepted your answer!

Comment: @RyosukeYokota if your domain axis is not numeric, you can take a look to other axis specs. For strings, it's OrdinalAxisSpec.